# Do I need a UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, canada

My husband is a Canadian citizen. He has sponsored me for Permanent Residence which I should receive soon. I'm going to travel to Canada via London, and I'm planning a layover of 21 hours.  At one time, I was in the UK for 6 years and I want to use the layover to visit my friend. Can I enter the UK without a visa during my layover time, or do I need a visa?

Comment: Depending on what documents you have for Canada at the time of your trip, the answer may depend on your citizenship.